# Callback requires const function, how to pass instance member of object

Tags: c++, callback, webkit, javascriptcore

I am using WebKitGTK+ in a larger GTKmm/C++ application.  I am using JavaScriptCore to interact with the WebKitWebFrame and JSContext within.

I am stuck now as I need to interact with a GTK GUI component when a javascript function is called.  To this end I found the [JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/JSObjectRef_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback) function.

```
JSStringRef str = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("ClickCallback");
JSObjectRef func = JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback(m_jsRef, str, ClickCallback);
JSObjectSetProperty(m_jsRef, JSContextGetGlobalObject(m_jsRef), str, func, kJSPropertyAttributeNone, NULL);
JSStringRelease(str);
```

Where the callback must be defined as a static function with def:

```
static JSValueRef ClickCallback(JSContextRef ctx, JSObjectRef func, JSObjectRef self, size_t argc, const JSValueRef argv[], JSValueRef* exception)
```

So everything is working except I need my object instance in the callback to get back at the GUI component I need to manipulate.

There are tons of similar questions on SO but most focus on passing the object instance into the callback.  I can not see a way of doing that with this API.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a static function or even a member function.

Comment: I hate it when APIs let you register a callback without letting you pass some kind of "context" cookie (usually a void*).

Comment: @Emile -- Exactly. V8 allows this by attaching a special `Data` pointer to the `Arguments` object which is passed to the function, at least. Saves so much trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback is required to be a pointer to a free function, so no amount of magic can get you to pass a member function directly. One common solution is to make an intermediate global free function that holds the object instance:

```
JSValueRef ClickCallback(...)
{
  Foo & obj = getInstance(); // implement this somehow
  return obj.click(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you can make this a static member function of your GUI class. The main point is that you must obtain the instance reference separately and call the member function yourself if you have to pass a plain function pointer to your API.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, thanks.  This is how I was proceeding.  I was hoping for some magic though it make it a little cleaner...